# How to access kubernetes injected env variable in rails config initializers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

We are replacing AWS Access key & secret with new auth mechanism https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/

So now we have AWS_ROLE_ARN and AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE env variables which will be injected when pod gets created and therefore these variables are not present in config map. 
We have a rails app with config initializer where we use these variables but deploy fails with error "key not found". 
To get around this we added keys in config map with dummy data, considering variable value will get overwritten once pod gets deployed. key not found issue got fixed with this hack but we get error

`Missing :web_identity_token_file parameter or invalid file path provided for Aws::AssumeRoleWebIdentityCredentials provider`

My understanding is app gets initialized in container and then it gets deployed into pod but variables are only available when container is added into the pod. 
Is there way I we can get around this in kubernetes or I need to move my app code from initializer and use it only when making actual request to aws?

**Note:** I am new to kubernetes.

**EDIT**
Ruby code

```
Client.configure do |config|
  config.credentials = Aws::AssumeRoleWebIdentityCredentials.new(
    client: Aws::STS::Client.new(region: 'us-west-2'),
    role_arn: ENV.fetch('AWS_ROLE_ARN'),
    web_identity_token_file: ENV.fetch('AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE')
  )
```

secrets.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: "${NAME}-secrets"
  namespace: "${NAMESPACE}"
data:
  AWS_ROLE_ARN: "${AWS_ROLE_ARN}"
  AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE: "${AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE}"
```

Comment: you should put real secrets in config map, and dummy data in Dockerfile. ENVs are not overwritten after deployment AFIAK

Comment: Can you provide some of the actual source code and deployment artifacts involved here; for example, the Ruby code referencing `ENV`, and the YAML files that set those environment variables?

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze, updated my question with details.

Comment: Does something in your deployment spec attach these secrets to the pods?